# Powershell Automation: from Runspace to PSSession

Tags: powershell, c#, winrm

In a C# application I'm working on, I have a runspace which I'm using to run remote commands, like so:

```
var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo()
{
    Scheme = WSManConnectionInfo.HttpsScheme,
    Port = 5986,
    SkipCACheck = true,
    SkipCNCheck = true,
    ComputerName = Address,
    OperationTimeout = (int) TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4).TotalMilliseconds,
    OpenTimeout = (int) TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds,
    Credential = new PSCredential(_userName, _password)
};
var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();
```

Then I can use the runspace using code like this:

```
public List<PSObject> Run(Command command)
{
    using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershell.Runspace = Runspace;
        powershell.Commands.AddCommand(command);
        var output = powershell.Invoke();
        ThrowOnError(powershell);
        return output.ToList();
    }
}
```

This works and I'm able to run both remote commands and scripts.

Now, I would like to `Copy-Files` from local to remote and I'm trying to leverage the remote session targeting capabilities of the cmdlet:

```
Copy-Item -FromSession $remoteSession C:\TEMP\test.txt -Destination C:\TEMP\test.txt
```

To do this I need to pass a `$remoteSession` object (which I don't have) into a local runspace (which I have).

I could just call `New-PSSession` in the local runspace and call it a day, but, AFAICT, runspace and sessions are close cousins.

**Could I in some way "extract" a PSSession object from my runspace instance?**

Comment: Calling `New-PSSession` in the source runspace _is_ the correct solution, not sure what you mean by "close cousins".